# How to selenium.GetXpathCount for this element?

Tags: c#, xpath, selenium, rc

```
ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_0
ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_1
ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_2
...
ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_19
ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_20
```

What expression should I use to count all 21 elements?

I've used

```
decimal count = selenium.GetXpathCount("//*[@id='ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_.*']");
decimal count = selenium.GetXpathCount("//*[@id='ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_[.*]']");
decimal count = selenium.GetXpathCount("//*[@id='ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_.']");
```

but none of them worked... please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
//*[starts-with(@id,'ctl00_Content_ctl00_chkProduct_')]
```